# C11 Unicode Support

Tags: c, unicode, c11

I am writing some string conversion functions similar to `atoi()` or `strtoll()`. I wanted to include a version of my function that would accept a char16_t* or char32_t* instead of just a char* or wchar_t*.

My function works fine, but as I was writing it I realized that I do not understand what char16_t or char32_t are. I know that the standard only requires that they are an integer type of at least 16 or 32 bits respectively but the implication is that they are UTF-16 or UTF-32.

I also know that the standard defines a couple of functions but they did not include any *get or *put functions (like they did when they added in `wchar.h` in C99).

So I am wondering: what do they expect me to do with char16_t and char32_t?

Comment: Convert to UTF-8, what else?

Comment: @Deduplicator: If that's what they expected you to do with them you'd think they would have given you functions to do that...

Comment: Are you planning to support not only `0..9` (U+0030..U+0039) (and potentially `A..Z/a..z`, for up to the customary highest level, base-36) but all other characters marked "Numeric" in the full Unicode table as well? 'Coz this includes typographic forms (super- and subscripts; circled numbers up to 20(!)) and script specific forms (Arabic numbers, Hebrew numbers), as well as Roman numbers, Ancient Greek and "Counting rods" and lots more.

Comment: @Jongware I support '0'-'9' 'a'-'z'/'A'-'Z' and up to base 64 with 'A'-'Z' and '$'/'_'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's a good question with no apparent answer.

The `uchar.h` types and functions added in C11 are largely useless. They only support conversions between the new type (`char16_t` or `char32_t`) and the locale-specific, implementation-defined multibyte encoding, mappings which are not going to be complete unless the locale is UTF-8 based. The useful conversions (to/from `wchar_t`, and to/from UTF-8) are not supported. Of course you can roll your own for conversions to/from UTF-8 since these conversions are 100% specified by the relevant RFCs/UCS/Unicode standards, but be careful: most people implement them wrong and have dangerous bugs.

Note that the new *compiler-level features* for UTF-8, UTF-16, and UTF-32 literals (`u8`, `u`, and `U`, respectively) are potentially useful; you can process the resulting strings with your own functions in meaningful ways that don't depend at all on locale. But the *library-level* support for Unicode in C11 is, in my opinion, basically useless.

Comment: Do you know how much it limits portability to assume the multibyte-encoding is UTF-8? (I mean, is this something like "the standard allows non-2's complement" which can often be ignored in practice, or is this really something I should worry about?)

Comment: @mafso: I don't think the *internal* representation of strings as UTF8 is a potential portability problem. But how are you going to display your text if there is no portable (almost certainly "per definition") way to show the result?

Comment: @Jongware: I know that it's not portable (in theory). But this "locale-specific multibyte-encoding" and "locale-specific wide character encoding" stuff was standardized with C89, a time where Unicode encodings weren't of that wide-spread use as they are today (IIRC they weren't even standardized by that time). My question is, if it nowadays is safe to assume Unicode encodings _in practice_.

Comment: @mafso: On Windows (except cygwin) it's **never** UTF-8. MS has a bs technical excuse but the real reason is just pushing their UTF-16 based interfaces instead of the standard functions.

Answer (score 3):

Testing if a UTF-16 or UTF-32 charter in the ASCII range is one of the "usual" 10 digits, +, - or a "normal" white-space is easy to do as well as convert `'0'-'9'` to a digit.  Given that, `atoi_utf16/32()` proceeds like `atoi()`.  Simply inspect one character at a time.

Testing if some *other* UTF-16/UTF-32 is a digit  or white-space - that is harder.  Code would need an extended `isspace(), isdigit()` which can be had be switching locales (`setlocale()`) if the needed locale is available.  (Note: likely need to restore locale when the function is done.

Converting a character that passes `isdigit()` but is not one of the usual 10 to its value is problematic.  Anyways, that *appears* to not even be allowed.

Conversion steps:

1. Set locale to a corresponding one for UTF-16/UTF-32.
2. Use `isspace()` for white-space detection.
3. Convert is a similar fashion for `your_atof()`.
4. Restore local.

Comment: And don't forget that UTF-16 and UTF-32 both have big-endian and little-endian variants, and you might care.

Comment: @JohnH: How can this be relevant for UTF-32?

Comment: @mafso The big/little endian variants does apply to both UTF-16 and UTF-32.  At the _byte_ level, the 2 or 4 bytes have an order that atypically mis-matches the byte order of the software.  That can be rectified using various byte re-order functions.  With a Unicode code-point >= 0x10000, and coding is UTF-16, the order on the 2 UTF-16 surrogates sometimes occurs in big or little endian order.  Only one of these is proper (forget which).  When the incorrect one is used, it should flag as an encoding error, though some systems are lenient (non-complaint).

Answer (score 0):

This question may be a bit old, but I'd like to touch on implementing your functions with `char16_t` and `char32_t` support.

The easiest way to do this is to write your `strtoull` function using the `char32_t` type (call it something like `strtoull_c32`). This makes parsing unicode easier because every character in `UTF-32` occupies four bytes. Then implement `strtoull_c16` and `strtoull_c8` by internally converting both `UTF-8` and `UTF-16` encodings to `UTF-32` and passing them to `strtoull_c32`.

I honestly haven't looked at the Unicode facilities in the C11 standard library, but if they don't provide a suitable way for converting those types to `UTF-32` then you can use a third party library to make the conversion for you.

There's [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/), which was started by IBM and then adopted by the Unicode Consortium. It's a very feature-rich and stable library that's been around for a long time.

I started a UTF library ([UTFX](https://github.com/tholberton/utfx)) for C89 recently, that you could use for this too. It's pretty simple and lightweight, unit tested and documented. You could give that a go, or use it to learn more about how UTF conversions work.