# How to use Unicode in C?

Tags: c, unicode, utf

I am developing an application in C and it must accept characters from every language. I am targeting Linux/Windows. What is the best way to implementing this, *considering that performance is important in this case*?

Comment: There are a few libraries that can help you handling Unicode and recoding between different formats.

Comment: Also, when you say "performance is important" you first need to ask yourself: Is it *really*? Never code for "performance", code for readability and maintainability first and foremost. Then you *measure*, *profile* and *benchmark* to find possible bottlenecks (if it's not acceptable as it is) and tune those only. Don't fall into the trap of premature optimization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C11 Unicode Support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26106647/c11-unicode-support) and [Light C Unicode Library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313555/light-c-unicode-library)